# Numbering problem when citing previous reference in text appended to a citation (REVTeX)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, revtex

I want to use the function `\cite{[{prepended text}][{appended text}]item}` to prepend/append text to a citation to cite a previous bibliography entry.
This is very useful when a paper has been reprinted in a book.

Here is a minimal example of the problem, take the following code:

```
\documentclass[aps,10pt,notitlepage]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{Bibliography fail}
\maketitle
  \cite{book}
  \cite{[][{. Reprintend in~\cite{book}}]paper}
  \cite{paper2}
  \cite{paper3}
  \bibliography{error}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image: result]
the book is correctly cited in the appended text, but for some reason the next citation gets the same number as the one just cited.
After this occurrence numbering goes on as usual.

Do you have any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: Unhelpful update: I contacted RevTeX support and basically they have told me that I'm trying to do something for which this functionality is not designed...